# PrestaShop turn off module when installing new

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I want to turn off ps_customersignin module when I install my new module because it literally replace this module, in install function I did:

```
   $query = 'UPDATE `ps_module` SET `active` = "0" WHERE `name` = "ps_customersignin"';
    
    return parent::install()
        && $this->registerHook('displayNav2')
        && $this->registerHook('header')
        && $this->registerHook('actionFrontControllerSetMedia')
        && Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($query)
        && $this->_clearCache('*');
```

It changes value in database but It doesnt seem to turn off module is there any way to turn off module when I install another module?
I have lastest Presta version, clear install.

Answer (score 1):

Check the function **disable()** in Module class,

you'll need to remove the module entry in **ps_module_shop** table,
but you can just use the built-in static method **Module::disableByName('ps_customersignin')** to
do it the "core" way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user3256843 answer I found out solution - disableByName is deprecated but using

```
Module::getInstanceByName('ps_customersignin')->disable();
```

Works just fine and after uninstalling

```
Module::getInstanceByName('ps_customersignin')->enable();
```

And everything seems fine :)